# I want to extract all the values that a class object holds

Tags: python, azure, loops, recursion

I have an object **Vm** of Type
`<class 'azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine'>` I want to iterate over this object by a loop so that I don't have to manually extract the values.

Yes I've tried `isinstance` to check whether the value is of type `<class 'azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine'>` and extract but in the next iteration it fails.

For example let's consider vm to be an object

- to access the vm size I will have to do `vm.hardware_profile.vm_size`
- and similarly to access os type value I will have to do this `vm.storage_profile.os_disk.os_type`

What I'm trying to achieve here is that if I pass the `vm` object it should return all the end values. Any help or tips are greatly appreciated and thanks in advance

The code that I have written

```
def iterdict(d):
    for k,v in d.items():        
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            iterdict(v)
        else:            
            print (k,":",v)

for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all():
    print(iterdict(vars(vm)))
```

And the output that i've been getting

```
name : arun-scheduler
type : Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
location : eastus
ml-scheduler : Test
stop_time : 2020-12-25 15:22:40.042295
plan : None
resources : None
identity : None
zones : None
hardware_profile : {'additional_properties': {}, 'vm_size': 'Standard_A1_v2'}
storage_profile : {'additional_properties': {}, 'image_reference': <azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.models._models_py3.ImageReference object at 0x000001AD6D5964C0>, 'os_disk': <azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.models._models_py3.OSDisk object at 0x000001AD6D596EB0>, 'data_disks': []}
additional_capabilities : None
os_profile : {'additional_properties': {}, 'computer_name': 'arun-scheduler', 'admin_username': 'xxxxxx', 'admin_password': None, 'custom_data': None, 'windows_configuration': None, 'linux_configuration': <azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.models._models_py3.LinuxConfiguration object at 0x000001AD6D596100>, 'secrets': [], 'allow_extension_operations': True, 'require_guest_provision_signal': True}
network_profile : {'additional_properties': {}, 'network_interfaces': [<azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.models._models_py3.NetworkInterfaceReference object at 0x000001AD6D596850>]}
diagnostics_profile : {'additional_properties': {}, 'boot_diagnostics': <azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.models._models_py3.BootDiagnostics object at 0x000001AD6D5966A0>}
availability_set : None
virtual_machine_scale_set : None
proximity_placement_group : None
priority : None
```

Output that I expect:

it should extract all the objects which are there in the Input

Comment: you can use another loop and check the values of the dict, Inside the loop you can use same code you are using

Comment: its just not one level....i need an answer with recursion...so that it can extract all the values from the object

Comment: It may not be possible. Because the core code may be implemented in another language and this is simply a wrapper, you may not be able to access the elements via the dict method. Instead, you will have to use the dir function, remove all magic methods and try to find all the elements.

Comment: Thanks but i tried dir just now .....it didnt seems  to be the solution that im looking for...but thanks eitherway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion. Here I'm using `hasattr` to check if it's has `__dict__` attribute(`vars()` method return the results of `obj.__dict__`).

```
def props(x):
    if hasattr(x, '__dict__'):
        res = {}
        for k, v in vars(x).items():
            if isinstance(v, list):
                res[k] = [props(e) for e in v if hasattr(e, '__dict__')]
            elif hasattr(v, '__dict__'):
                res[k] = props(v)
            else:
                res[k] = v
        return res
```

**Example:**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, p, q):
        self.p = p
        self.q = q

class B:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class C:
    def __init__(self, a, b, lst):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.lst = lst
```

**Output:**

```
>>> a = A(123, 'abc')
>>> b = B(a, {'xyz': 123})
>>> c = C(a, b, [B(a, 1), B(a, 2)])
>>> props(c)
{'a': {'p': 123, 'q': 'abc'},
 'b': {'x': {'p': 123, 'q': 'abc'}, 'y': {'xyz': 123}},
 'lst': [{'x': {'p': 123, 'q': 'abc'}, 'y': 1},
  {'x': {'p': 123, 'q': 'abc'}, 'y': 2}]}
```

Comment: there is one flaw in this ..if you can see in the output that i have posted there **network_profile : {'additional_properties': {}, 'network_interfaces': [<azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.models._models_py3.NetworkInterfaceReference object at 0x000001AD6D596850>]}** it has list of object and its not able to extract data out of those

Comment: it will be a great help

Comment: Thank you..it worked just  the way i wanted it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clasObject.__dict__` and it will return a dictionary of object encapsulated variables

Comment: its not extracting fully...its behaving same as vars(object)

Comment: I guess now your problem is decapsulating nested objects. To my knowledge you need to make a recursive function for it. after calling `vars(object)` loop through the keys and then call `isinstance(key, type)` if it's true then it's an object that can be decapsulated.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to do the same ....but I'm unable to achieve it...as I'm also new to programming

Answer (score 0):

Something nice about Microsoft Azure's Python API is it has a lot of features built-in and the code is open source. For instance, check out the [code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/compute/azure-mgmt-compute/azure/mgmt/compute/v2019_07_01/models/_models_py3.py) for this exact class. This inherits from msrest.serialization.Model, which you can also find the [code](https://github.com/Azure/msrest-for-python/blob/master/msrest/serialization.py) for.

Note all Model classes provide a .serialize() method that turns the class into a json string for passing to Azure remote services. Before doing anything needlessly complicated and home grown, I would just try calling that on your VirtualMachine objects and see if it gives you a string representation you can use.